# Omit Items in jsonencode Based on a Bool Value

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

All but one caveat of using feature flags for specific backend services has been solved. In this case, a feature flag allowing for the optional creation of an RDS Aurora Postgres Instance based on environment has been defined simplay as `var.rds_aurora_postgres_enabled`. In the `aws_iam_policy` that RDS instance needs to be listed as a resource, if it is in use.

This policy below is attached to a lambda in the form of

```
module "lambda_start_coalesce_instances" {  
  source                    = "xxx"   
  application               = var.application  
  service                   = "${var.service}-env-start-${var.lane_color}"  
  policy = {
    json = aws_iam_policy.coalesce_schedule_instance_policy.policy
  } 
    ...
}
```

I thought of creating two policies one without a refrence to `module.rds_aurora_postgres.primary_rds_cluster_arn` and one with, however, lambda can only take one policy. That may still be doable and use the feature flag to specify which policy. Before I go down that path, I would like to ask if there is a way to omit specific "Statements" inside the jsonencode below?

```
resource "aws_iam_policy" "coalesce_schedule_instance_policy" {
  name = "${local.namespace_coalesce}-coalesce-schedule-instance-policy"
  policy =jsonencode({
     "Version": "2012-10-17",
     "Statement": [       
         {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [                    
                "rds:DescribeDBInstances",
                "rds:DescribeDBClusters",
                "rds:ListTagsForResource",
                "dms:DescribeOrderableReplicationInstances",
                "dms:DescribeReplicationTasks",
                "dms:DescribeReplicationInstances",                    
                "dms:ListTagsForResource",
                ],
            "Resource": "*"
          },
          --**--WOULD LIKE TO OMMIT THIS STATEMENT BASED ON A BOOL VALUE
          {
             "Effect": "Allow",
             "Action": [                       
                "rds:StartDBCluster",
                "rds:StopDBCluster"
             ],
             "Resource": [
               "${module.rds_aurora_postgres.primary_rds_cluster_arn}"
             ]
          },
          {
             "Effect": "Allow",
             "Action": [                                                                                               
                "rds:StartDBInstance",
                "rds:StopDBInstance",                              
             ],
             "Resource": [
                "${module.rds_sqlserver.db_instance_arn}"
             ] 
          },
          {
             "Effect": "Allow",
              "Action": [                                                                                                                                        
                 "dms:ModifyReplicationInstance"
              ],
              "Resource": concat(values(aws_dms_replication_instance.dms_instance_bronze)[*].replication_instance_arn, values(aws_dms_replication_instance.dms_instance_silver)[*].replication_instance_arn, values(aws_dms_replication_instance.dms_instance_on_prem_to_rds)[*].replication_instance_arn)
           },
           {
              "Effect": "Allow",
              "Action": [                                                                         
                 "dms:ModifyReplicationTask",
                 "dms:MoveReplicationTask",
                 "dms:StartReplicationTask",
                 "dms:StopReplicationTask",                      
              ],
              "Resource": concat(values(aws_dms_replication_task.onprem_to_s3_replication_task)[*].replication_task_arn,  values(aws_dms_replication_task.s3_to_rds_sqlserver_replication_task)[*].replication_task_arn,  values(aws_dms_replication_task.s3_to_rds_aurora_postgres_replication_task)[*].replication_task_arn, values(aws_dms_replication_task.s3_silver_to_s3_gold_replication_task)[*].replication_task_arn) 
           },
           {
              "Effect": "Allow",    
              "Action": [
                 "s3:GetObject"
              ],
              "Resource": "${module.s3_config.bucket.arn}/*"
           }  
        ]
    })
  tags = local.common_tags
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `jsonencode` and JSON to provide policies, I would suggest using the built-in data source, [`aws_iam_policy_document`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/iam_policy_document). It is much easier to make it work with terraform logic than what you are currently trying, plus it is more human-readable as well. Here is how I would try to do what you want:

```
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "coalesce_schedule_instance_policy" {
  statement {
    sid    = "RDS"
    effect = "Allow"
    actions = [
      "rds:DescribeDBInstances",
      "rds:DescribeDBClusters",
      "rds:ListTagsForResource",
      "dms:DescribeOrderableReplicationInstances",
      "dms:DescribeReplicationTasks",
      "dms:DescribeReplicationInstances",
      "dms:ListTagsForResource"
    ]
    resources = ["*"]
  }

  dynamic "statement" {
    for_each = var.some_bool_value ? [1] : []
    content {
      sid    = "RDSCluster"
      effect = "Allow"
      actions = [
        "rds:StartDBCluster",
        "rds:StopDBCluster"
      ]
      resources = [
        module.rds_aurora_postgres.primary_rds_cluster_arn
      ]
    }
  }

  dynamic "statement" {
    for_each = var.some_bool_value ? [1] : []
    content {
      sid    = "RDSInstance"
      effect = "Allow"
      actions = [
        "rds:StartDBInstance",
        "rds:StopDBInstance",
      ]
      resources = [
        module.rds_sqlserver.db_instance_arn
      ]
    }
  }

  dynamic "statement" {
    for_each = var.some_bool_value ? [1] : []
    content {
      sid    = "DMSModfiy"
      effect = "Allow"
      actions = [
        "dms:ModifyReplicationInstance"
      ]
      resources = concat(values(aws_dms_replication_instance.dms_instance_bronze)[*].replication_instance_arn, values(aws_dms_replication_instance.dms_instance_silver)[*].replication_instance_arn, values(aws_dms_replication_instance.dms_instance_on_prem_to_rds)[*].replication_instance_arn)
    }
  }

  dynamic "statement" {
    for_each = var.some_bool_value ? [1] : []
    content {
      sid    = "DMSReplicationTask"
      effect = "Allow"
      actions = [
        "dms:ModifyReplicationTask",
        "dms:MoveReplicationTask",
        "dms:StartReplicationTask",
        "dms:StopReplicationTask"
      ]
      resources = concat(values(aws_dms_replication_task.onprem_to_s3_replication_task)[*].replication_task_arn, values(aws_dms_replication_task.s3_to_rds_sqlserver_replication_task)[*].replication_task_arn, values(aws_dms_replication_task.s3_to_rds_aurora_postgres_replication_task)[*].replication_task_arn, values(aws_dms_replication_task.s3_silver_to_s3_gold_replication_task)[*].replication_task_arn)
    }
  }

  dynamic "statement" {
    for_each = var.some_bool_value ? [1] : []
    content {
      sid    = "S3GetObject"
      effect = "Allow"
      actions = [
        "s3:GetObject"
      ]
      resources = [
        "${module.s3_config.bucket.arn}/*"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

This will add the statements to the policy based on some boolean variable, which I have called here `some_bool_value` since you have not provided it in the question. If you replace it with the real variable name, this should work. Then, in the IAM policy resource, you would just do the following:

```
resource "aws_iam_policy" "coalesce_schedule_instance_policy" {
    name   = "${local.namespace_coalesce}-coalesce-schedule-instance-policy"
    policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.coalesce_schedule_instance_policy.json
}
```

Comment: Thanks again for your help! Seems like a wise choice.

Comment: Yeah, I tend to stay away as much as possible from mixing JSON and HCL. :)